# Interleaving of digits of $e$ and $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers

What happens if we form a number by taking every other digit of, say, $\pi$? Has this type of construction been studied? Also, what if we interleave the digits of $e$ and $\pi$?

Comment: There is a PBS Infinite series video on this, and also a mathoverflow post; ill try to find it

Comment: Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bG7cCXqcJag

Comment: Here is the post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265310/if-i-exchange-infinitely-many-digits-of-pi-and-e-are-the-two-resulting-num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a new number.  Like almost all numbers, it's probably transcendental.

Any construction involving digits depends on the radix (or base) in which you're representing the numbers.  So it's nothing really intrinsic to the number or numbers involved.

Comment: Probably normal as well.